# Technique to match a message by criteria to node in the cluster

Tags: message-queue, cluster

I have global message queue with multiple different producers, and a cluster with N nodes of consumers. Each consumer receives a message and may decide to process it or to put it back to the queue if not interested. Each message has a relation to the `project`. The amount of projects is greater than amount of nodes (`project_amount / nodes_amount ~= 10`). Each project has unique but not sequential ID (this ID is attached to each message in queue). I want to make each node to handle only fixed set of projects to avoid resource synchronization between nodes, each node knows total amount of nodes and self sequential number, but cluster can be scaled and amount of nodes may change at any moment. Also, amount of projects is not limited, and new project can be added at any time without nodes notice.

Example diagram (`PX1`, `PX2`, `PA1` and `PZ9` - projects):
[image: diagram]

So the question: how can I filter messages on consumer to be sure that all messages for one project will be processed only on one consumer-node and to be sure that messages for any project will be processed on some consumer?

Comment: The dispatching and filtering should be already done at he _Global queue_, not at the _Consumer_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not really, in my case (SQS) consumer takes a message from queue and decide to process it or to put it back.